# bat file behaves differently when run from windows scheduler

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, 7-zip, task-scheduler

I have a .bat file S:\BACKUP_db\copytofileserver.bat, which takes some files and zip them to the network drive. Its first command is to delete the old backup at specific network path, then pack the files in S:\BACKUP_db folder. See:

```
echo ================================================== >> log.txt
echo %date%, %time%: Backup started >> log.txt
set dow=%date:~0,3% >> log.txt

echo %time%: deleting existing backup... >> log.txt
del /F /S /Q /A "\\192.168.1.249\homes\backup\%dow%.7z"  >> log.txt
echo %time%: OK >> log.txt

echo %time%: packing and saving new backup... >> log.txt
if exist *.Backup S:\BACKUP_db\7za a -t7z -mx=1 "\\192.168.1.249\homes\backup\%dow%.7z" S:\Backup_db\*.Backup -m0=BCJ2 -m1=LZMA:d23 -m2=LZMA:d19 -m3=LZMA:d19 -mb0:1 -mb0s1:2 -mb0s2:3 >> log.txt
echo %time%: OK >> log.txt

echo %time%: deleting local backup files...  >> log.txt
del /F /S /Q /A S:\backup_db\*.Backup  >> log.txt
echo %time%: OK  >> log.txt

echo %date%, %time%: Backup finished >> log.txt
```

when I run this .bat file manually, it works like a charm (file is very big, cca 50 GB, when zipped it has cca 5 GB), however when I run this .bat file in windows scheduler job, it starts ok, deletes files in network location but then it is always stuck during execution of 7zip program. Windows scheduler says last run result= 0x41306.

Settings of the windows scheduler task seem correct: run only when user is logged on, "run with highest privileges" doesn't make a difference, etc.

Strange is, it worked before, now it is getting stuck and I have no idea why. Sometimes a 16MB zipped file is created at network destination, sometimes 2GB file, it seems random.

**second round:** 
well, this is what happend now - I set the bat file to run at specified time and observed black window with my commands being executed. It crashed again, the file was created: "\192.168.1.249\homes\qi\BackupQIostra\po  .7z", it has 0.6 GB, it is supposed to have at least 5 GB. Also in the bat file I substituted all local paths with "%~dp0" as suggested, no change. Log file output:

```
================================================== 
po 04. 08. 2014, 11:00:00,40: Backup started 
11:00:00,44: deleting existing backup... 
Deleted file - \\192.168.1.249\homes\backup\po  .7z
11:00:00,49: OK 
11:00:00,50: packing and saving new backup...
```

after this, I run the .bat file by double-click and observed what happens, zipping goes well, 5 GB file is created, log output is complete:

```
================================================== 
po 04. 08. 2014, 11:37:37,60: Backup started 
11:37:37,61: deleting existing backup... 
Deleted file - \\192.168.1.249\homes\backup\po  .7z
11:37:37,63: OK 
11:37:37,63: packing and saving new backup... 

7-Zip (A) 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18
Scanning

Creating archive \\192.168.1.249\homes\backup\po  .7z

Compressing  20225_20140804030000 - Copy.Backup
Compressing  20225_20140804030000.Backup

Everything is Ok
12:53:59,52: OK 
12:53:59,52: deleting local backup files...  
Deleted file - S:\BACKUP_db\20225_20140804030000 - Copy.Backup
Deleted file - S:\BACKUP_db\20225_20140804030000.Backup
12:54:02,18: OK  
po 04. 08. 2014, 12:54:02,18: Backup finished
```

Comment: Getting a normal batch to run normally in the scheduler is always fun. "Why it be so weird" :-). If your indicating that it fully operated before via the scheduler, but fails at various times?  What if it has something to do with files being open/locked?  You have the zipping going to your log, but what did the zip program itself complain about?  Also (I forget) sometimes the lack of a output window, a program expects to be able to talk to ?

Comment: well, 7zip itself will make its output to the log file only after it is finished :( so when run from scheduler, the last thing I see in the log is the line: "time: packing and saving new backup..." and since it always creates a file in network location, I suppose it is running for some time and then something nasty happens and it crashes and log remains blank.

Comment: troubleshoot. track it down to something smal like one line or a few lines that work differently

Comment: 7zip execution works differently, that I already know. I can't go deeper within that exe file :) Maybe I'll try to change compression program altogether and see if it is a problem with 7zip.

Comment: I have a Wav player used to talk out certian events, it has the same output of a Author (copyright and author stuff). It also failed. I just stumbled around running it VIA the run schedule, and ended up changing the "Hidden" flag configuring for vista (instead of 7) and using a starting program , one that hides windows. Cripes if I knew which one fixed it.  So i am wondering if that copyright output itself is possible to be the problem?  After all it is not showing when run that way?

Comment: Maybe you can make the zip action smaller and faster for testing purposes only, then keep testing it via the task scheduler run schedule, being different in its own way when run from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems like delegating the task to hstart utility solved the issue. It is kind of workaround and I loose an ability to get any feedback from 7zip, but the bat file now works ok and completes the task.

so I replaced this:

```
if exist *.Backup %~dp0\7za a -t7z -mx=1 "\\192.168.1.249\homes\qi\BackupQIostra\%dow%.7z" %~dp0\*.Backup -m0=BCJ2 -m1=LZMA:d23 -m2=LZMA:d19 -m3=LZMA:d19 -mb0:1 -mb0s1:2 -mb0s2:3 >> log.txt
```

with this:

```
if exist *.Backup "%~dp0hstart\hstart.exe" /NOCONSOLE /RUNAS /NOUAC /SHELL /WAIT /D="%~dp0" /BELOWNORMAL "%~dp07za a -t7z -mx=1 "\\192.168.1.249\homes\qi\BackupQIostra\%dow%.7z" %~dp0*.Backup -m0=BCJ2 -m1=LZMA:d23 -m2=LZMA:d19 -m3=LZMA:d19 -mb0:1 -mb0s1:2 -mb0s2:3" >> log.txt
```

**BUT:**

now when I observed it being run by scheduler, I noticed a strange thing. My .bat file is started, hstart runs 7zip command externaly and the main black command window which waits for completion of hstart/7zip task disappears after ~5mins! But the 7zip external command is still running, hidden, and completes correctly. Of course, the log file is not complete, still stack in the middle, since the main window crashed. So now I know for sure, that it is the main command window that is crashing.

Answer (score 0):

I think current directory `%systemroot%\System32` when start with service or scheduler. Probably need to add:

```
CD S:\BACKUP_db\
```

Comment: Better yet is to use `CD "%~dp0`, which will work even if you move the files. You also should probably put `%d0` on the line above (or below) that, to switch the same drive as the batch file. Grabbing the batch file's path is a good habit to get into.

Comment: well, I'll try to run it like you guys suggest here, I'll post the results, though I'm a bit sceptical that the problem is in paths, because all commands are executed properly, just 7zip is being stopped randomly in the middle of the zipping process.

Answer (score 0):

I also got .bat file run from yask scheduler. My problem was: at "Settings" tab it has "stop the task if it runs longer then:" and i changed that. But inside trigger it has the same thing. This what stopped my console application in 30 mins (set by default there). So it worked manually, but had `0x41306` error run by task scheduler.

I got here while searching for solution, hope it helps someone.